# Looking for a freeware client-side IIS Log Analyzer

Tags: iis, log-files

I am looking for a IIS Log Analyzer that has the following attributes:

1. Does not require IIS
2. Is a standard client application
3. Can simply take the log file as an input and come back at me with pretty graphs and charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Analog](http://analog.cx/) - awesome product.

Here's a [sample report](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sret1/stats/), including charts like this:
[alt text http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sret1/stats/browsum.png](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sret1/stats/browsum.png)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) from Microsoft. If you download the log files, it can parse them and you can perform SQL-like queries on the log files, even on multiple files at a time.

Oops, just noticed your last requirement. There will not be any graphs, but the data can be imported into something like Excel to produce graphs. I'd be interested to know if there are any that do the whole lot for you. If not, it sounds like a development opportunity! :D

Comment: +1 for LogParser. Amazingly powerful, but has a learning curve for sure. Worth the time investment. Also, great point about using Excel to produce the eye candy.

Answer (score 1):

I use IIS Log File Viewer by Alexander Higgins.  Not sure if his site is still up, but Its a nice tool to view them away from the server.